# Group an object by multiple keys using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, lodash

The data looks like this:

```
const data = [
  {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'},
  {'a': '10', 'b': '20', 'c': '30'}
]
```

I want this:

```
const aArray = ['1','10']
     ,bArray = ['2', '20']
     ,cArray = ['3', '30']
```

I did this:

```
...
return {
  aArray = _.values(_.mapValues(data, 'a'))
  bArray = _.values(_.mapValues(data, 'b'))
  cArray = _.values(_.mapValues(data, 'c'))
}
```

It works but doesn't look clean. What's the cleanest way to group an object by multiple keys?

Comment: What exactly doesn't look clean? Looks very readable and short enough to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using plain JavaScript:

```
const data = [
  {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'},
  {'a': '10', 'b': '20', 'c': '30'}
]

const aArray = data.map(x => x.a)
     ,bArray = data.map(x => x.b)
     ,cArray = data.map(x => x.c)
```